# Trying to click on a hyperlink that includes spaces

Tags: java, selenium, hyperlink

I am trying to click on a hyperlink with a space using Java and Selenium.  Here is a sample of the code

```
<h3 class="side menu">
    <a class="side-menu" href="/configurations">
    <span class="menu-icon ca"></span>Configuration
    </a>
</h3>
```

I have tried using xpath starts-with and contains with no luck.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(text(),’Configuration’)]")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle dynamic element use `WebDriverWait` and `elementToBeClickable` with expected conditions.Use the following `Xpath` locator strategies.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath('//a[@class="side-menu"][normalize-space(.)="Configuration"]')));
element.click()
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath('//a[@class="side-menu"][contains(.,"Configuration")]')));
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to add a forward slash:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(text(),'/configuration')]")).click();
```

It works for me in the Chrome console if I type:

```
$x("//a[starts-with(@href,'/configuration')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use normalize-space when writing the xpath for the text, which will trim the leading and preceding white chars (spaces/tabs/newlines)

Here is how you should do it in your question.

```
//a[normalize-space(.)='Configuration']
```

Tested the xpath in chrome console for click() successfully using javascript.